# combining multiple sum case statements

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where charge groups are made up a multiple of charge codes.

So, for example, a Destination Charge Group consists of charges codes like PortCharges, Cartage, Insurance etc.
And a Freight Charge Group consists of charge codes like Freight, Landside Charges, freight surcharges etc.

I use a query like

```sql
Select
    Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.AccChargeCode.AC_ChargeGroup = 'DST' Then dbo.AccTransactionLines.AL_LineAmount Else 0 END) AS Destination,
    Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.AccChargeCode.AC_ChargeGroup = 'FRT' Then dbo.AccTransactionLines.AL_LineAmount Else 0 END) AS Freight

from xxx
```

The issue comes in where the Destination Charge Group also contains the charge code Agency.

I need to show the Destination total and the Freight Total in separate rows, but I need to show the sum of Destination and Freight amounts as Disbursements, but excluding the Agency Amount. The reason for that is the amounts that comprise the Destination and Freight Charge Groups are amounts disbursed on behalf of the client, but Agency is our fee, so is not an actual disbursement.

To put some figures into the picture as an example, the total Destination amount equals 1000.  The total Freight amount equals 750.  The Agency amount equals 250.  So, using these figures Disbursements would be 
Destination  = 1000
Freight      =  750
Disbursments = 1500.

I have tried to derive the Disbursements figure by using the following

```sql
Select (Disburse - Agency) AS Disbursements
        from
        (
        Sum(CASE WHEN dbo.AccChargeCode.AC_ChargeGroup IN('DST','FRT') 
                 THEN dbo.AccTransactionLines.AL_LineAmount ELSE 0 END) AS Disburse,
            CASE WHEN dbo.AccchargeCode.AC_Code = 'Agency' 
                THEN dbo.AccTransactionLines.AL_LineAmount ELSE 0 END AS Agency
        )
```

but that results in an error.

can anyone please assist me?

Many thanks

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/32281)

Comment: The SUM() function can only be provide a single parameter - by including two separate CASE statements inside the SUM() function you are trying to do SUM(x, y) - but SUM() cannot accept these two parameters.  If you want to have multiple conditions in a CASE expression, then you can just do CASE WHEN a THEN b WHEN j THEN k WHEN x THEN y ELSE z END

Comment: Sample data and expected results (as a properly formatted table) would help immensely.